# Ubuntu not recognizing HDMI or USB-C display output

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

My Lenovo Yoga slim 7, with AMD ryzen 5 4500u and RX vega 6 integrated graphics, does not detect any display output. I have tried both HDMI and USB-C. Xrandr output:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

And:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Renoir
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fce0000000-fcefffffff memory:fcf0000000-fcf01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:80500000-8057ffff
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, kernel version `5.4.0-45-generic`, any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the resolutions? What is the resolution of the monitor you are trying to connect?

Comment: Maybe installing the Hardware Enablement Stack would help...